# Pinescript. Calculate the number of bars per day

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

```
//@version=5
indicator("Ebanina", overlay=true)

barscum = ta.barssince(ta.change(time("D"))) + 1
var table ebanina = table.new(position.bottom_center, 4, 5)
table.cell(ebanina, 2, 0, str.tostring(barscum), text_color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0), text_halign = text.align_right)
```

I am trying to display the number of bars per day on different instruments. Everything is fine, except for cryptocurrency. On cryptocurrency, the value is dynamic and changes with each bar. And I can't find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I came only to this decision. Once a year, you need to rewrite the date.
Maybe I'll find an answer by then.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Ebanina", overlay=true)
openses = timestamp("10 Aug 2023 00:00")      
closeses   = timestamp("11 Aug 2023 00:00") 
timeses(tm) =>
    var int _bar = na 
    if time_close[1] <= tm and time >= tm
        _bar := bar_index
    _bar   
beginning   = timeses(openses)
end  = timeses(closeses)
muchbars  = end - beginning
var table ebanina = table.new(position.bottom_center, 4, 5)
table.cell(ebanina, 2, 0, str.tostring(muchbars), text_color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0), text_halign = text.align_right)
```